# Cleanup script with find - No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I am using the following to find and delete a group of sub volumes:

```
find /.snapshots/ -name backup-* -type d -exec btrfs subvolume delete {} \;
```

It works, but I get unexpected output from find:

```
Delete subvolume (no-commit): '/.snapshots/backup-24-11-2021'    
find: ‘/.snapshots/backup-24-11-2021’: No such file or directory    
Delete subvolume (no-commit): '/.snapshots/backup-25-11-2021'    
find: ‘/.snapshots/backup-25-11-2021’: No such file or directory
```

I am no pro in unix, so its a bit puzzling for me, why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `find` reaches `/.snapshots/backup-24-11-2021`, it checks whether it's a directory, as directed by `-type d`. It is a directory, so `find` runs `btrfs subvolume delete /.snapshots/backup-24-11-2021` as directed by `-exec …`. Once that's done, `find` has just hit a directory, so it recurses into that directory. Recursing into directories is, after all, the main point of `find`. But the directory has just been removed (by `btrfs subvolume delete`). So `find` notices that something is wrong and reports it.

Tell `find` not to recurse under the snapshots that you're deleting. This is generally applicable when looking for whole directory trees to delete.

```
find /.snapshots/ -name 'backup-*' -type d -exec btrfs subvolume delete {} \; -prune
```

(Note: I also fixed the missing quotes around the `-name` clause. Without quotes, `backup-*` is expanded when `find` is run, so the command won't do what's intended if the current directory has files matching `backup-*`, or if you're using a shell that errors out on non-matching globs.)

But actually, this is probably the wrong command altogether. You're instructing `find` to look everywhere under `/.snapshots`. For example, if there's a directory `/.snapshots/saved-for-posterity/usr/src/backup-app`, your command instructs `find` to call `btrfs subvolume delete /.snapshots/saved-for-posterity/usr/src/backup-app`, which doesn't make sense. Assuming that all snapshots are subdirectories of `/.snapshots`, pass `-maxdepth 1` to avoid recursing further:

```
find /.snapshots/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'backup-*' -type d -exec btrfs subvolume delete {} \;
```

The only difference between that and

```
btrfs subvolume delete /.snapshots/backup-*
```

is that this calls `btrfs subvolume delete` with the literal argument `/.snapshots/backup-*` if there are no backups at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error messages because you delete the directories before `find` has had a chance to look inside of them.  When `find` is done with the dircetory that contained the now deleted directories, it tries to enter e.g. `backup-24-11-2021`, but fails with the "No such file or directory" error, because it's gone.

You may solve this by using `-depth` with `find`, which makes the utility do a depth-first search of the directories instead.  Finding and deleting e.g. `/.snapshots/backup-25-11-2021` would only happen once `find` has looked at all other directories beneath that path.

```bsh
find /.snapshots -depth -name 'backup-*' -type d \
    -exec btrfs subvolume delete {} \;
```

Also note that we need to quote the argument to the `-name` test as it contains a filename globbing character.

The other way to do it is to use `-prune`, i.e., to delete that path from the search tree of `find` when it's found so that `find` doesn't try to then go down into it.

```bsh
find /.snapshots -name 'backup-*' -type d -prune \
    -exec btrfs subvolume delete {} \;
```

The third way to do it, if all your `backup-*` directories always live directly under `/.snapshots`, is to not use `find` at all:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
for dir in /.snapshots/backup-*; do
    btrfs subvolume delete "$dir"
done
```

The above shell loop would call `btrfs subvolume delete` with all directories matching the pattern `/.snapshots/backup-*`.  In the `bash` shell, setting the `nullglob` shell option would cause the shell to remove any non-matching globbing pattern rather than retaining the pattern unexpanded.

If the command `btrfs subvolume delete` is able to take more than one pathname as argument, you may even get away with doing just

```bsh
shopt -s failglob
btrfs subvolume delete /.snapshots/backup-*
```

... where the `failglob` shell option in the `bash` shell would prevent the command from executing if there were no pathnames matching the given globbing pattern.

Comment: Thanks @they! Both yours and @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' posts are outstanding so I had difficulties deciding which one to accept. I would have both if possible!